# what is the chat box of face-book known as

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i am working on asp.net

i want to make a chat room which should be attach like facebook

can any tell me do's and dont's

wht is it called 
how can i start ?
designing  part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic chat using ASP.NET with AJAX:
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Basic-Chat-Using-ASP-NET-AJAX